# Rails Server-side validations - belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck.  Trying to get to what would seem like a simple validation working, but I still can't get this to work.

Here's the setup:

Models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :course

  validates_presence_of :city,
                    :message => "City cannot be blank",
                    :allow_blank => true,
                    :if => Proc.new {|location| location.nil? || (!location.nil? && location.course.format != 'Live') } 

end
```

What I'd like to do is, if a course has anything BUT 'Live' selected, then allow a blank city to be saved in the locations table.  Else, if the course.format is 'Live', throw back an error.

I believe that it was working on the validation where there was no location defined.  But, when updating a course and changing the format to 'Live', the validation doesn't quite work.

In rails, how do you always reference another column in a related table, like the one I have above?  If it's a new course, then the course isn't created yet while the validations are being checked, so course.nil? is true.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_presence_of :city,
                    :message => "City cannot be blank",
                    :allow_blank => true,
                    :if => Proc.new {|location| location.nil? || (!location.nil? && location.course.format != 'Live') }
```

In above validation :allow_blank has no relation with :if block.
Try like this

```
validates_presence_of :city,
                    :message => "City cannot be blank",
                    :if => Proc.new {|location| 'your_conditions'} 

Now this validation works when 'your_condition' will return true.
```